# [SOLVED]W2K8 DNS server is resolving private IP addresses to the internet

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

OK, so I've read a bunch of articles which revolve around my problem, but none of them have a clear answer. There is a ton of arguing back and forth and while I understand there are a few schools of thought regarding this topic,                  I'd like to try to clear the air.

This is all run out of my home both for convenience and to learn.

I run two W2K8 servers, both with AD, DNS and other services, and a separate server which is also my windows VPN server. mydomain.com is both my local AD domain name, and I also own mydomain.com, and I have it pointed to my home's IP address. I have a bunch of A-records that I use with different services. Most are only used internally, however some need to be resolved externally. Obviously none of the local only DNS records need to resolve unless you are connected via LAN or VPN (i.e. DC1.mydomain.com needs to be local only, while helpdesk.mydomain.com needs to resolve both internally and externally.)

I would rather not resolve LAN IP addresses to the public internet because I believe it is bad practice. So my questions is, how to I set up DNS so it resolves all records to LAN users (and VPN users, but DNS shouldn't know the difference between LAN users and VPN users, right?), but only certain records to the internet?

Comment: Don't get it, what's the problem? (there are no question marks...)

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit that. Basically I want DNS to resolve all records to users on the LAN, but only allow resolution of certain records to the internet. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Let me see if I got it. You want your local DNS to resolve all local addresses, but resolve only selected internet addresses?

Comment: If I ping DC1.mydomain.com from inside my LAN, it resolves to 192.168.100.231. That is correct and working. However if I ping it from anywhere else on the internet, it STILL resolves to 192.168.100.231, which should not happen. It should time out, not get resolved. But if I ping VPN.mydomain.com, it resolved to my public IP address from both inside and outside my network. That needs to continue to happen.

Comment: The fact that your DC1 resolved to internal IP means nothing - it's not like it's routable...  
Anyway, do a whois query (plenty of websites to do this) to see who holds this record. Also, generally, I think that having the same domain name both on the inside and the outside is bad - it can cause unnecessary confusion.

Comment: I know it's not routable, for me it's not a security issue, just seems like bad practice. I ran a whois query and everything was expected, it's my name servers and the registrar is 1and1 as it should be. When I set up my network years and years ago, I knew very little and it seemed like a good idea at the time. If I ever rebuild it, I'll definitely do things different. As I said initially however, I did this all to learn. So at least that's working - I'm learning lol,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not doable. What you would need is a split dns setup - which requires multiple dns servers.

I suggest you move the internet side of mydomaain out to a third party and do not host that DNS yourself. Cloudflare does that for free.

Comment: So, cloudflaire or the like would handle DNS requests for internet users for the mydomain.com domain (which would be authoritative for mydomain.com) AND I would have a DNS server set up on my local LAN which would not be visible to the public internet, which would ALSO be authoritative for mydomain.com domain? I suppose the idea is that my local DNS server would simply resolve DNS requests for mydomain.com and not forward them to the cloudflaire DNS server?

Comment: That is why normally you do not se the same domain. You would for example use internal.mydomain.com as domain internally. Ten mydomain.com can always go to the internet. Using the same doman name is really not standard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure split-DNS properly. Basically, you need proper DNS zones configured for internal and external resources, with IP addresses set appropriately.

http://www.thesuperkev.com/2012/10/setting-up-split-dns-in-windows-server.html